# Dataflow Template usePublicIps as parameter

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How do I pass/set "usePublicIps" as runtime parameter in Google dataflow templates, which is running in Google VPC project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter usePublicIps cannot be overriden at runtime. This parameter needs to be set/unset while generating the Dataflow Template.

Below command shows how to disable it for a template.

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=class -Dexec.args="--project=$PROJECT \
--runner=DataflowRunner --stagingLocation=bucket --templateLocation=bucket \
--usePublicIps=false --subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-cloud-project/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/mysubnetwork"
```

Additionally you will also have to turn on Private google access for a subnetwork as mentioned in this link https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#configuring_access_to_google_services_from_internal_ips and use that in the maven build as a subnetwork parameter.